# ¿Como se recorre e imprime los valores de un array indexado de dos dimensiones en php?

Tags: php, matriz

Este array he querido recorrerlo pero hasta ahora lo logre con dos for y me sale un error que dice Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ si alguien sabe porque se lo agradecaria mucho me dijera

```
$input  = array( "php","4.0",array("verde", "rojo"));
```

Este es el for que utilice tambien utilice un foreach pero no me funciono

```
for ($fila=0; $fila < count($input); $fila++) { 
//echo $input[$i]. "<br>";
  for ($columna=0; $columna < count($input); $columna++) { 
    
    echo $input[$fila][$columna];

  }
  echo "<br>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que uno de los valores es a su vez un array. Entonces, puedes preguntar si es array mediante [`is_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-array.php), para leerlo abriendo un nuevo bucle.

Por ejemplo, con `for`:

```
$input  = array( "php","4.0",array("verde", "rojo"));

for ($i = 0, $size = count($input); $i < $size; ++$i) {
    if (is_array($input[$i])) {
        for ($j = 0, $size = count($input[$i]); $j < $size; ++$j) {
            echo $input[$i][$j]."<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo $input[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Con `foreach`:

```
$input  = array( "php","4.0",array("verde", "rojo"));

foreach ($input as $row) {
    if (is_array($row)) {
        foreach ($row as $v) {
            echo "$v<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "$row<br>";
    }
}
```

Si quieres evitar un segundo bucle, para este caso concreto puedes usar [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) para extraer los valores del array anidado.

Con `for` sería:

```
$input  = array( "php","4.0",array("verde", "rojo"));

for ($i = 0, $size = count($input); $i < $size; ++$i) {
    if (is_array($input[$i])) {
        echo implode("<br>",$input[$i]);
    } else {
        echo $input[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Y con `foreach` sería:

```
$input  = array( "php","4.0",array("verde", "rojo"));

foreach ($input as $row) {
    if (is_array($row)) {
        echo implode("<br>",$row);
    } else {
        echo "$row<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: de eso me di cuenta que lo tomaba como otro valor del array al mismo array t agradezco mucho la aclaracion yo estoy empezando en esto y me sera muy util su ayuda